# How to correct errors in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am very new to app development. I am trying my hands on my first app i.e. browser app and trying to convert a responsive website into app. My practice codes and error are attached. 
Project: To make a browser app for a single responsive website. If feed google.com, it should open google.com and so on and no other domain. Looking forward to your suggestions. Thank You.
PS: Internet Permission is enabled in the AndroidManifest XML.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

In activity.main XML-->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
     android:layout_width="422dp"
      android:layout_height="731dp" -->
    <!--   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" /> -->

    <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

    </resources>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**In main activity java -->

```
package com.example.myapplication;**

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView gbWebview;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        gbWebview.loadUrl("www.google.com");
        WebSettings webSettings = gbWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        gbWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() );

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(gbWebview.canGoBack() ) {
            gbWebview.goBack() ;

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    }
```

Error:

```
2020-05-12 09:09:33.426 7816-7816/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7816
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class resources
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class resources
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class resources
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.resources" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-yjFN1lkmHHB0IQDMPn8cyg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-yjFN1lkmHHB0IQDMPn8cyg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: That `<resources>` block does not belong in a layout. It would go in a `res/values/` folder, usually in a file named `styles.xml`. If that's already there, then just delete it from the layout. Otherwise, create that file, if needed, and move it there.

Comment: Thanks Zain for the reply. I tried doing it as mentioned by you. but it still shows the same error.

Comment: To at least get rid of the current, specific error, you simply need to remove the whole `<resources>` block from that layout. If you've done that successfully, then the error is different now, or it's happening in a different place. If you haven't successfully removed that, well, why not?

Comment: Cheers. It worked. The next challenge is sign in via gmail using webview.